# Generic Data Structure problem with Integer comparison

Tags: generics, integer, compare, adt

I am trying to implement a generic ADT in Java, similar to a linked list. I had a problem when it is instantiated as Integer, because Find(E e) method fails in the comparison. It happens for values greater than 127.   I suppose that it is caused by an implicit byte casting. I don't know how to fix the error and preserve the generic feature.

```java
public class MyList<E> {
    private NodoDoble<E> head;
    private NodoDoble<E> tail;
    private int size;
    public MyList(){...}
    public boolean IsEmpty(){...}
    public int Size(){...}
    public void Clear(){...}
    public boolean Add(E e)
    public E Get(int index){...}  
    public boolean Add(E e, int pos){...}
    public int Find(E e){
        NodoDoble<E> iterator = head;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < size && !found) { 
            if( iterator.value == e){
                return i;
            } else {
                iterator = iterator.next;
                i++;
            }        
        }
            return -1;
        }
    }
//...
}
```

Main:

```java
MyList<Integer> L1 = new MyList<>();
L1.Add(45);
L1.Add(120);
L1.Add(130);
System.out.println(L1.Find(120));
System.out.println(L1.Find(130));
MyList<String> L2 = new MyList<>();
L2.Add("dog");
L2.Add("cat");
System.out.println(L2.Find("cat"));
```

Output:

```
1
-1
1
```

```java
public class NodoDoble<E> {
    public E value;
    public NodoDoble<E> next;
    public NodoDoble<E> prev;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!

Use Object casting and compare using "equals"

```
if( ((Object)iterator.value).equals(e)){
        return i;
    } else {
        iterator = iterator.next;
        i++;
    }
}
```